# how to insert PHP code snippet in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

my code-

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['errors']="failed";
?>


<head>

    function myfunc()
    {        
         alert(<?php echo $_SESSION['errors']; ?>);
    }
</head>

<body onload="myfunc();">
```

**but alert msg is not popping up.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two errors in your code:

- You are missing `<script>` tags
- You are missing single/double quotes in alert

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['errors']="failed";
?>


<head>

<script>
    function myfunc()
    {        
         alert('<?php echo $_SESSION["errors"]; ?>');
    }
</script>
</head>
```

You might want to put the `myfunc()` in `window.load` event or some `click` event to test it. Additionally, as rightly suggested by ThiefMaster, you may want to use the `addslashes` function for the `$_SESSION["errors"]` in the `alert`.

**Note:** It is assumed that file extension for your code is **php**.

Comment: If on a PHP version that supports it, I would suggest using `json_encode` to properly quote and escape the string from PHP. `addslashes` does the job most of the time, but who knows what kind of stuff is in that string? There could be newlines!

Comment: @Aistina: agreed but only oop knows whether he will be expecting json format and thereby use json_decode but his session data seems to be pure scalar string.

Comment: Using `json_encode` on a string just returns that string formatted for use in Javascript code. Example: `$str = 'This is an "example".'; echo json_encode($str);` would print `"This is an \"example\".";`.

Comment: actually it was inside `script` tag but I forgot to copy here.

Answer (score 2):

PHP will just print out `failed`, it won't print out the string delimiters along with it, so make sure you put them in:

```
function myfunc()
{        
     alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['errors']; ?>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, it's impossible to insert PHP code snippet in javascript. Because it's nonsense JS engine don't understand PHP.
You can only *generate* whole javascript using PHP.

So, to ask such a question, you must provide

1. an exact javascript code you want to get.
2. an example of input data
3. and a result of your own code execution, compared to [1]

Comment: A harsh, but accurate statement.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you should ensure that your php output doesn't contain anything breaking the javascript string:

```
function myfunc()
{        
     alert('<?php echo addcslashes($_SESSION['errors'], "'/\\"); ?>');
}
```

Note that I also escape the forward slash to ensure that `</script>` doesn't end the script tag (there is no other good way except escaping forward slashes to prevent that).